# Rackup with HTTPS support

Tags: ruby, https, rack, rackup

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445506/rack-web-server-and-https-tutorial), which doesn't really solve my problem but at least maybe lets me phrase my question the right way.

I have a simple Camping app that I launch via `rackup`.  I'd like to be able to test the app over a secure connection (self-signed server cert would be fine) but since I don't have root on my development box it'd be better if I could secure the default server for rackup (Mongrel, maybe?  WEBrick?  not sure how to check) since that's lightweight and works more or less out of the box.

Again, I a) don't have root, b) haven't configured an Apache server before, and c) don't particularly want to learn if I can help it.  If there's no simple way to do this, I guess that's life, but if I could just pass an option or two to rackup, or update my config.ru, to provide HTTPS support, that'd be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test HTTPS you need a certificate. You can create a self-signed certificate to test on your machine like this: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Most ruby server (if not all) do not handle certificate themselves, you need a server like apache or nginx to handle this stuff. The question you were referring to is explaining how to proceed with apache.I would suggest to use Apache with a self-signed certificate.

As for the root access... you are developing on a machine you do not have root access to?

Comment: Yup, no root here.  Sometimes in a corporate environment it just can't be helped.  Unfortunately it sounds like "there's no simple way to do this", and as I said in the question, I guess that's life.  ::sigh::

Comment: You could create the certificate elsewhere and copy it to your work machine. Also I think you do not need root to run apache or nginx(only to install them).